# input onClick and onFocus collision

Tags: reactjs, events, input

I have an `<input>` element, and I want to show content (`div`) below the input if it has focus.
Also, on every click on the input, I want to hide/show the `div`.
The problem is that if the input is not focused, than clicking the input will trigger both `onClick` and `onFocus` events, so `onFocusHandler` will run first so the menu will appear but immidately after that `onClickHandler` will run and hide it.
This is the code (that doesn't work):

```
import React from 'react';

const MyComp = props => {

    /*
    ...
    state: focused, showContent (booleans)
    ...
     */

    const onFocusHandler = () => {
        showContent(true);
        setFocused(true);
    }

    const onClickHandler = () => {
        if (focused) {
            showContent(false);
        } else {
            showContent(true);
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <input
                onFocus={onFocusHandler}
                onClick={onClickHandler}
            />
            {
                showContent &&
                <div>MyContent</div>
            }
        </>
    );
};

export default MyComp;
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very odd desired behavior as an active toggle is rather opposed to an element being focused or not. At first I couldn't see any clear way to achieve the behavior you desire. But I thought it *could* be achieved.

1. Use the `onMouseDown` handler instead of the `onClick` handler.
2. Use `onFocus` handler to toggle on the extra content.
3. Use `onBlur` handler to toggle off the extra content.

Code:

```
const MyComp = (props) => {
  const [showContent, setShowContent] = useState(false);

  const onFocusHandler = () => {
    setShowContent(true);
  };

  const onBlurHandler = () => {
    setShowContent(false);
  };

  const onClickHandler = () => {
    setShowContent((show) => !show);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input
        onBlur={onBlurHandler}
        onFocus={onFocusHandler}
        onMouseDown={onClickHandler}
      />
      {showContent && <div>MyContent</div>}
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit input-onclick-and-onfocus-collision]

**Note:** It should be noted that `onMouseDown` isn't a true replacement to `onClick`. With a click event the mouse down and up *have* to occur in the same element, so if. user accidentally clicks *into* the input but then drags out and releases, the `onClick` event should not fire. This may be ok though since the focus event fires before the click event so the input may get focus and toggle the content on *anyway*. Maybe this quirk is acceptable for your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

You should you `onBlur` event to `setContent` to `false`. There is no need to use the `onClick` handler for that.

Comment: But as I said, if the input is focused, and the user click on it, it should hide the content. and clicking again will show it, etc.

Comment: So you don't need to check if it is focused... I mean, one functionality is to showContent when it first focus the input and then just toggling on/off when clicking. I would do directly `setShowContent(!showContent)` and the `onBlur` event will `setShowContent(false)`